# JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I use Spring tomcat web server. Try to print objects list in jsp. In locale machine tomcat 7 server jsp file works fine, but when i push it to remote tomcat 8 server I get this exception:

```
    org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/view/web/matches.jsp at line 52

49:                 <div class="row" id="home-content">
50:                     <div class="col-sm-8">
51:                         <section class="panel">
52:                             <c:forEach var="i" begin="0" end="${matches.size()-1}" step="1">
53:                                 <c:if test="${i == 0 || matches.get(i).league != matches.get(i-1).league}">
54:                                     <table class="table table-condensed matcheslist">
```

Also logger write this debug error in log file.

```
DispatcherServlet:1225 - Error rendering view [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView: name 'web/matches'; URL [/WEB-INF/view/web/matches.jsp]] in DispatcherServlet with name 'DispatcherServlet'
```

Comment: did you set matches in any scope?

Comment: thanks,  matches list size in server was 0